# How to fix random seed for BERTopic?

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I'd like to fix the random seed from [BERTopic](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic) library to get reproducible results. Looking at the code of BERTopic I see it uses numpy. Will using `np.random.seed(123)` be enough? or do I also need to other libraries as random or pytorch as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486629/bert-binary-textclassification-get-different-results-every-run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the `random_state` variable using UMAP, but you have to also send the other default parameters to the UMAP constructor or the model will break.

What this looks like in practice is:

```
umap = UMAP(n_neighbors=15,
            n_components=5,
            min_dist=0.0,
            metric='cosine',
            low_memory=False,
            random_state=1337) 
model = BERTopic(language="multilingual", umap_model=umap)
topics, probs = model.fit_transform(content)
```

By default, `umap_model` is set to `None` in the `BERTopic` constructor. Internally if that is not provided, it sets one up with default params [here in the code](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/362ccc6b9acbf9e15a24edcbcfdeb81a2dd007ff/bertopic/_bertopic.py#L229C5-L229C5).

Note that `low_memory` is a param in both constructors, and if the `BERTopic` constructor isn't called with that in it, it internally sets it to `False`.

Comment: h/t to @sxyxxn for setting me on the right path, but it seems you can't just send the `random_state` param by itself or it breaks the model.

Comment: This worked for me. model = BERTopic( umap_model=umap), without multilingual

Answer (score 3):

you can fix the random seed

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
from umap import UMAP

umap_model = UMAP(random_state=42)

topic_model = BERTopic(umap_model=umap_model)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: The example above is de-facto mentioned in the [https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/faq.html#why-are-the-results-not-consistent-between-runs](official documentation)

Comment: @EthanChen please see my answer below. I had the same issue and worked through it.