# Evaluating DQN, Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, vehicle-routing, dqn

I am running this DQN algorithm that is trying to minimize the total distance traveled by a vehicle (VRP).
In the training, as you can see in the images, everything works fine. The loss is decreasing, the average length in decreasing, and the reward is increasing.

However, in the evaluation phase the model behaves in an unexpected way. I am running 100 evaluation iterations. In the first run, the results are good. But, the next runs of evaluation give me sometimes good results and sometimes very bad results. In the good results I get min total distance (min length) value of `4`, but sometimes the evaluation return a min value of `13` even though the evaluation is done on the same trained model.

So my question is this a normal behavior? And is there a way to improve these evaluation results?

P.S:

- the number of episodes in training is 4000 ( i tried on 10000 also and it's the same thing)
- the data is random array of coords and an adjacency matrix of euclidean distance between the coords. For every new episode there's a new random coords and distance arrays.
- the same thing for evaluation. I do 100 iterations of evaluation and for each iteration new random data
- In the evaluation I don't use any penalties or rewards. I only use them in the training.
  I am using pytorch in this project

Here's an example of the evaluation output:
shortest avg length found: 5.406301895156503 (this is the value from the training)
Now here are an example of 2 solutions from evaluation

Solution 1:

```
[0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 10]
length 4.955087028443813
```

Solution 2:

```
[0, 4, 9, 3, 13, 0, 7, 13, 0, 10, 0, 6, 11, 5, 12, 1, 12, 0, 2, 12, 0, 8, 0]
length 10.15813521668315
```

The first 100 evaluations are similar to solution 1, and i rerun evaluation for another 100 i get results similar to solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the source code would definitely be helpful. There could be several reasons,

1. Do you [shuffle the *training* data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks)?
2. How is the reward function designed? Is it a function of the duality gap?
3. Is `cuda` configured to be [deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354461/reproducibility-and-performance-in-pytorch/56358318#56358318)?
4. Do you put your model to [`eval` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018578/what-does-model-eval-do-in-pytorch) before the evaluation step?
5. What is the density of the unexpected behavior results across all evaluation iteraitons? Perhaps the model only needs more & longer episodes or that your model is overfitting.
6. How is the training & test data are split? The topological complexity of the VRP or TSP instances could have an impact.